# Side effects of varying door and frame thickness

Tags: furniture, design, cabinetry, hinges

I'm designing a custom wardrobe with doors for my tiny NYC apartment. I am planning to have a 3/4" thick birch frame with 1" full overlay aluminum-framed mirror doors. Are there any side effects to having the doors thicker than the frame?

To generalize this question consider three cases:

- Doors thinner than frame.
- Doors and frame are the same thickness.
- Doors thicker than frame.

What are the pros and cons of each considering we have full overlay doors with full overlay hinges?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Can I just confirm you did mean thickness here, as in stock thickness, rather than *width*? I hope this doesn't seem needlessly nitpicky but it's vitally important to use the established terminology for board dimensions to prevent confusion — we actually had a very similar query just recently where this happened.

Comment: @Graphus, thanks for going over this. Yup, I meant stock thickness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any side effects to having the doors thicker than the frame?

No.

> To generalize this question consider three cases:
> • Doors thinner than frame. • Doors and frame are the same thickness. • Doors thicker than frame.

3/4" material is very common, so with the same thickness or thicker it's no problem, follow normal practice.

If doors are thinner the only issue is maybe finding suitable screws that will not go through the door, or the tip arrives slightly below the surface and creates a bump.

A good tip for such doors is to use metalworking screws, which have a flat tip and finer threads. They have better hold in wood too!